# Object Collision Issue - Weird Behaviour - Unity

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, collision

I wondering if someone could give me a hand with this problem I'm having with objects and collisions in Unity.

I have a sphere object being controlled by the users phone's accelerometer. The sphere moves around fine but once it hits a wall the sphere starts acting weird. It pulls in the direction of the wall it collided with, starts bouncing, and just overall not responsive anymore to the movement of the phone.

Any idea as to why this could be happening?

Here is the script used to control the player's sphere.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed;
void Update() {
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
    dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;
    dir.z = Input.acceleration.y;
    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        dir.Normalize();

    dir *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(dir * speed);
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Pickup") {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does "collects objects" mean, exactly?

Comment: Also, it would be a lot easier to help you with your problems if you provided information about how exactly your game object is configured. Is there a rigidbody, a collider? Is the rigidbody kinetic? What methods are you using to move the object?

Comment: Also, try to reduce the complexity of the problem. For example, if you replace the accelerometer controls with just using ordinary input and run inside the editor (but leave everything else the same), does the problem reproduce?

Comment: Basically its a sphere the user controls to collect objects for points.

Comment: The sphere is a rigid body and has a sphere collider and the walls of the room are have box colliders.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your object has a 'Rigidbody' component, and, I suppose, it's not a kinetic rigidbody. Basically, it behaves just like it should: a real physical object will not pass through another object, that is the most basic behaviour of a physics engine. However, since you don't operate with the physics-based object using forces, but manually change it's position, you break a level of abstraction. In result, you move the object inside the wall, and now it can't get out.

Use [ApplyForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) method instead. If you want to *pull* or *push*  object (instead of just *move*, which contradicts the fact that these objects are managed by physics) in a certain direction every frame, you should use `ForceMode.Acceleration` (or `ForceMode.Force`, if you want the effect to depend on the mass) every *physics frame*, which means that you have to use `FixedUpdate` method instead of `Update`.

Comment: I'll give what you wrote a try and let you know. As well thats the purpose of the walls is to keep the sphere from going over the edge of the level.